# Синтаксис SQL запрос SELECT

Tags: sql, mysqli

Ребята, доброй ночи!

Что не так с синтаксисом в запросе в строке 11? Голову сломал

Пишет вот это:

Notice: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''users'' at line 1 in

И с кавычками, и без, и с апострофом, никак не получается. В случае без кавычек отдается просто страница с формой ввода пароля без каких-либо уведомлений, там еще var_dump есть, так вот без кавычек и он молчит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Закомментировал строку 16

```
return $data;
```

Все заработало. Кто скажет почему?

Comment: про кавычки вам уже написали... А в следующий раз, пожалуйста, выкладываете примеры не картинкой, а текстом и убирайте лишнее. Раз вопрос по синтаксису SQL, то и приводите только сам запрос.

Comment: Наверно специально для вас, Mike, я и добавил что глазами надо смотреть на строку номер 11

Comment: А куда ваш return возвращает результат ? А то, что вы указали, что смотреть строку 11 ничего не меняет. представляете, если бы проблема оказалась более серьезной, что бы ответить на вопрос надо было бы скопировать ваш код и проверить. Сомневаюсь, что у кого нибудь было бы желание перебивать код с картинки...

Answer (score 3):

Вы используете одинарные кавычки, а нужно использовать апострофы `.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
```

Comment: И без кавычек, и с апострофами отдается пустая страница, на которой отображается только форма ввода, даже echo var_dump нет. Может и правильно с апострофами, но почему тогда пусто?

Comment: @Андрей код надо писать осмысленно.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ вопрос почему заработало. Если я правильно понял, приведенный вами код не является функцией и после того как вы используете **return** все что ниже не будет выполнятся. А у вас там ниже вывод информации